# Does CF10 support secure websocket wss?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfwebsocket

Can someone using CF10 confirm if CF10 supports secure websocket `wss://`?

[image]

http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/28/html5-websocket-security-is-strong/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked with Hemant. The answer is no, it is NOT supported now, but it is under progress to be added.

Comment: Any idea where would it be added to? CF10.0.1? or CF11+?

Answer (score 2):

On the basis of there being not a single mention of "secure websocket" or "wss" in the CF10 docs (according to Google), and in all the blogging Ray Camden has done on the topic there is not a single mention of it either, and indeed the only relevant match on all of Google for "cf10 wss" is back to this very question, I would say "no".

But that would be rather an odd implementation omission, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried hacking this on the websocketChannel.js file where the URL is created (line 18)

```
var lURL="ws://"+(_7e0)+":"+_cf_websocket_port+"/cfusion"+"/cfusion";
```

tried to do this

```
var lURL= (location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws") + "://"+(_7e0)+":"+_cf_websocket_port+"/cfusion"+"/cfusion";
```

But alas the wss:// connection would just never connect. BS I tell you .. pure BS!! The only issue really is with IE10 as it will not connect to an unsecured websocket channel initiated from a secure page.

Comment: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3434307 it's labeled Fixed, but I'm not sure when will this be available for us. CF11?

Answer (score 0):

> No it is not supported yet. However, it is being considered for
>   ColdFusion Splendor.

https://twitter.com/rakshithn/status/352722362799624193